# How to use Triangulation and Timing Advance distance calculation method together.

Tags: algorithm, gsm, signal-strength

For finding mobile location we know methods, *Triangulation* according to signal strength and finding location using *Timing Advance*. Now to improve accuracy we need to use both methods simultaneously. We are able to use both the methods independently but now able to use with each other to improve accuracy.

Can you please suggest a way by which we can use TA and Triangulation simultaneously.

I appreciate your help in this regard.
Thank you.

Comment: You should look at how http://locatioanpi.org does it.

Answer (score 0):

Triangulation method uses Network Management Report(NMR) which consists Timing Advance(TA) parameters. The mobile terminal regularly collects and forwards NMR to the serving cell to assist the network to make handoff decisions. If the NMR can be retrieved from terminal, then on the basis of cell id’s and received signal strengths from 3 or more neighbor cells, it is possible to estimate terminal location with triangulation. This can be done by approximating the user’s distance from 3 or more locations on the basis of the signal strength received.

Triangulating a mobile device involves three steps.

- Retrieve the signal strength values from the neighbor cells.
- Approximate the distances from the corresponding cells with the help of the received signal strength.
- Geo-coding to find the actual geographic location of the mobile device.

Location estimation of a terminal can be determined with by measuring either the radial distance, or the direction, of the received signal from two or three neighbor cells. Terminal sends out a RF signal. Three neighbor cell stations pick up the signal, calculate the signal strengths and *use calibrated data* to calculate the approximate distance based on signal strength. A server then aggregates the values to triangulate the precise position of the terminal.

There are many articles that have tried to find a suitable relation between signal strength and distance as *calibrated data* but signal strength varies according to terrain and changes drastically when a mobile device is present indoor due to multipath propagation.

There is no universal relation to calculate signal strengths for every location on the earth. For each location, site specific relations must be formulated.